# Unable to open Alfresco admin-consle.jsp

Tags: java, jsp, jsf, alfresco

When I try to launch the Alfresco's admin-console.jsp, the page does not move,It gives a blank page with no error

below is the jsp,

```
<h:panelGrid id="admin-panel" columns="1" cellpadding="6" cellspacing="6" border="0" width="100%">

<a:actionLink value="#{msg.manage_users}" image="/images/icons/users.gif" action="dialog:manageUsers" styleClass="title" rendered="#{NavigationBean.allowUserGroupAdmin}" />

<a:actionLink value="#{msg.manage_groups}" image="/images/icons/group.gif" padding="2" action="dialog:manageGroups" styleClass="title" rendered="#{NavigationBean.allowUserGroupAdmin}" />

<a:actionLink value="#{msg.category_management}" image="/images/icons/categories.gif" padding="2" action="dialog:manageCategories" actionListener="#{CategoriesDialog.resetCategoryNavigation}" styleClass="title" />

<a:actionLink value="#{msg.import}" image="/images/icons/import.gif" padding="2" action="dialog:import" actionListener="#{BrowseBean.setupSpaceAction}" styleClass="title">
<f:param name="id" value="#{NavigationBean.currentNodeId}" />
</a:actionLink>

<a:actionLink value="#{msg.export}" image="/images/icons/export.gif" padding="2" action="dialog:export" actionListener="#{BrowseBean.setupSpaceAction}" styleClass="title">
<f:param name="id" value="#{NavigationBean.currentNodeId}" />
</a:actionLink>

<a:actionLink value="#{msg.system_info}" image="/images/icons/info_icon.gif" padding="2" action="dialog:showSystemInfo" styleClass="title" />

<a:actionLink value="#{msg.node_browser}" image="/images/icons/node_browser.gif" padding="2" action="dialog:showNodeBrowser" styleClass="title" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

But in the logs, I could see,

```
Aug 7, 2013 2:33:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Renderer found for component {Component-Path : [Class: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: /jsp/admin/admin-console.jsp]} (component-family=javax.faces.ViewRoot, renderer-type=javax.faces.Grid)
Aug 7, 2013 2:33:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Renderer found for component {Component-Path : [Class: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: /jsp/admin/admin-console.jsp]} (component-family=javax.faces.ViewRoot, renderer-type=javax.faces.Grid)
Aug 7, 2013 2:33:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Renderer found for component {Component-Path : [Class: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: /jsp/admin/admin-console.jsp]} (component-family=javax.faces.ViewRoot, renderer-type=javax.faces.Grid)
Aug 7, 2013 2:33:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Renderer found for component {Component-Path : [Class: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: /jsp/admin/admin-console.jsp]} (component-family=javax.faces.ViewRoot, renderer-type=javax.faces.Grid)
Aug 7, 2013 2:33:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Renderer found for component {Component-Path : [Class: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: /jsp/admin/admin-console.jsp]} (component-family=javax.faces.ViewRoot, renderer-type=javax.faces.Grid)
Aug 7, 2013 2:33:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Renderer found for component {Component-Path : [Class: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: /jsp/admin/admin-console.jsp]} (component-family=javax.faces.ViewRoot, renderer-type=javax.faces.Grid)
Aug 7, 2013 2:33:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Renderer found for component {Component-Path : [Class: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: /jsp/admin/admin-console.jsp]} (component-family=javax.faces.ViewRoot, renderer-type=javax.faces.Grid)
Aug 7, 2013 2:33:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Renderer found for component {Component-Path : [Class: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: /jsp/admin/admin-console.jsp]} (component-family=javax.faces.ViewRoot, renderer-type=javax.faces.Grid)
Aug 7, 2013 2:33:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Renderer found for component {Component-Path : [Class: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: /jsp/admin/admin-console.jsp]} (component-family=javax.faces.ViewRoot, renderer-type=javax.faces.Grid)
Aug 7, 2013 2:33:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Renderer found for component {Component-Path : [Class: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: /jsp/admin/admin-console.jsp]} (component-family=javax.faces.ViewRoot, renderer-type=javax.faces.Grid)
Aug 7, 2013 2:33:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Renderer found for component {Component-Path : [Class: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: /jsp/admin/admin-console.jsp]} (component-family=javax.faces.ViewRoot, renderer-type=javax.faces.Grid)
Aug 7, 2013 2:33:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Renderer found for component {Component-Path : [Class: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: /jsp/admin/admin-console.jsp]} (component-family=javax.faces.ViewRoot, renderer-type=javax.faces.Grid)
Aug 7, 2013 2:33:41 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Renderer found for component {Component-Path : [Class: javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot,ViewId: /jsp/admin/admin-console.jsp]} (component-family=javax.faces.ViewRoot, renderer-type=javax.faces.Grid)
```

Looks like some rendering is not happening properly. I tried adding some logs into the page,but in vain. Can you please help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to navigate to the Admin console in Alfresco Explorer by hitting the JSP directly? Pretty sure that's not going to work. Instead, click the admin console icon, which is the first icon on the left at the top of the screen that looks like a little DJ console, see below:

[image: Click this for the admin console]

Do note that the Alfresco Explorer client is quite old and if possible, you should be using Alfresco Share instead. It also includes an admin console.

Comment: Jeff, you had attached any screenshots ? am not able to see it.

Comment: My Bad, I could see it from a windows machine,but not from Mac :(